# Vertical Connecting Lines with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, user-experience

I would like to have a connecting vertical line between each circle. The "Sections" are dynamic in vertical height.

[image: Menu]

Here is the current SASS:

```
@import '../sass/sa.common';
$color: $sa-gray-4;
$colorActive: $sa-green;
$colorComplete: $sa-green;
.progress-indicator {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  .step {
    margin-top: 40px;
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    &:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    &:last-child {
      div {
        &.circle {
          &:before {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    &.active {
      div {
        color: $colorActive;
        &.circle {
          border-color: $colorActive;
        }
        a {
          color: $colorActive;
        }
      }
    }
    &.complete {
      div {
        color: $colorComplete;
        &.circle {
          border-color: $colorComplete;
          &.filled {
            background-color: $colorComplete;
            color: $sa-white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    div {
      color: $color;
      display: table-cell;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 2px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align: middle;
      &.circle {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid $color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        &:before {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          margin-top: 26px;
          left: 13px;
          border: 1px solid $sa-gray-4;
          height: 125%;
        }
      }
      &.text {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        ul {
          margin: 0;
          margin-top: 15px;
          padding: 0;
          list-style-type: none;
          li {
            a {
              display: block;
              margin-top: 5px;
              &:first-child {
                margin-top: 0;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";
.btn.btn-green {
  background-color: #80b241;
  color: #ffffff; }
  .btn.btn-green:hover {
    background-color: #88bc47; }

.btn.btn-gray-1 {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #e7e5e1; }
  .btn.btn-gray-1:hover {
    background-color: #666666; }

.label.label-green {
  background-color: #80b241;
  color: #242424; }

.label.label-gray-1 {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #ffffff; }

.btn.btn-green {
  background-color: #80b241;
  color: #ffffff; }
  .btn.btn-green:hover {
    background-color: #88bc47; }

.btn.btn-gray-1 {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #e7e5e1; }
  .btn.btn-gray-1:hover {
    background-color: #666666; }

.label.label-green {
  background-color: #80b241;
  color: #242424; }

.label.label-gray-1 {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #ffffff; }

.progress-indicator {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 75px; }
  .progress-indicator .step {
    margin-top: 40px;
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    position: relative; }
    .progress-indicator .step:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      margin-top: 26px;
      left: 13px;
      border: 1px solid #ADABA6;
      height: 125%; }
    .progress-indicator .step:first-child {
      margin-top: 0; }
    .progress-indicator .step:last-child:before {
      display: none; }
    .progress-indicator .step.active div {
      color: #80b241; }
      .progress-indicator .step.active div.circle {
        border-color: #80b241; }
      .progress-indicator .step.active div a {
        color: #80b241; }
    .progress-indicator .step.complete div {
      color: #80b241; }
      .progress-indicator .step.complete div.circle {
        border-color: #80b241; }
        .progress-indicator .step.complete div.circle.filled {
          background-color: #80b241;
          color: #ffffff; }
    .progress-indicator .step div {
      color: #ADABA6;
      display: table-cell;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 2px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align: middle; }
      .progress-indicator .step div.circle {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid #ADABA6;
        border-radius: 50%; }
      .progress-indicator .step div.text {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px; }
        .progress-indicator .step div.text ul {
          margin: 0;
          margin-top: 15px;
          padding: 0;
          list-style-type: none; }
          .progress-indicator .step div.text ul li a {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 5px; }
            .progress-indicator .step div.text ul li a:first-child {
              margin-top: 0; }

.category-selector {
  margin-top: 30px; }
  .category-selector .header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #80b241; }
    .category-selector .header:before, .category-selector .header:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table; }
    .category-selector .header:after {
      clear: both; }
  .category-selector .section-container:before, .category-selector .section-container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .category-selector .section-container:after {
    clear: both; }
  .category-selector .section-container .section {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    min-width: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll; }
    .category-selector .section-container .section .item {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #80b241;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px; }
      .category-selector .section-container .section .item:last-child {
        border: 0; }
      .category-selector .section-container .section .item.active {
        background-color: #80b241;
        color: #ffffff; }
</style>
```

And the Markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="progress-indicator">
            <div class="step">
                <div class="circle">1</div>
                <div class="text">Select Category</div>
            </div>
            <div class="step active">
                <div class="circle">2</div>
                <div class="text">
                    Fill Out Listing
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Vital Fields</a>
                            <a href="#">Image Url</a>
                            <a href="#">Dimensions</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="circle">3</div>
                <div class="text">Bulk Options</div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="circle">4</div>
                <div class="text">More Options</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                SAVE AS DRAFT
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-gray-1">
                MOVE TO PUBLISH QUEUE
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="category-selector">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <h4>Select a Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-green">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-container">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="item" [ngClass]="{active: selectedCategory && category.id === selectedCategory.id}" *ngFor="let category of topLevelCategories" (click)="getSubCategories(category)">
                        {{category.displayName}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section" *ngIf="subCategories && subCategories.length > 0">
                    <div class="item" [ngClass]="{active: selectedSubCategory && subCategory.id === selectedSubCategory.id}" *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories" (click)="getFields(subCategory)">
                        {{subCategory.displayName}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Side Nav/Slide In
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker I added the rendered css in the question.

Comment: Your CSS [does not seem complete](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/86foqfdh/). Please link the missing resources. What's in `../sass/sa.common.sass`?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Common is all variables. Nothing else. Should probably rename it.

Comment: make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: I'm not going to make it work in the fiddle just so it will be off in your live example (because the fiddle is incomplete). You make it look like in the picture, I'll do it. This is totally up to you. Take your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browsers honor the display of `::before` on elements with `display:table`. (I have a hunch you are experiencing this in FF? - In Chrome they're displayed). There are two possible fixes:

1. Either replace `display:table` with `display:flex` and `display: table-cell` with `display: block`...
2. ...or use proper `html` elements (divs?) instead of pseudo-elements for lines.

Other notes you might find useful:

- remove `z-index` from `.step::before`
- change `height:125%` to `height:calc(100% + {N}px)` where {N} is the difference in `px` between the actual height of `.circle` and `40px` (top margin of `.step`). Using this technique you can control exact size of line and match the gap between the circles down to the pixel, thus not needing to hide the extra line length.

Hope the above makes sense and helps. Don't forget to `autoprefix`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
.step {
    position: relative;
    &:after {
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 30px; // magic number, try until you get the right positioning

         width: 1px;
         height: 100%;

         border-left: 2px solid $any-color-you-like;
   }
}
```

Make some adjustments, and it should work as you need.